# How to calculate rowMeans for dataframe?

Tags: r

I was trying to calculate rowMeans for a dataframe using these command

```
stamRow  <- data.frame(ProbeID=stam[,1], Means=rowMeans(stam[,c(-1,-2,-3)]))
stam$Means  <- rowMeans(stam[,-(1:3)])
```

But i am getting error in both case

```
rowMeans(stam[, -(1:3)]) : 'x' must be numeric
```

my dataset look like this:

```
 stam = 
ProbeId                     Chr     Position        Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5
CHR10FS00300029     10     3000293             0.132    0.135   0.312   0.724   0.889   
CHR10FS003018825        10     3018825             0.524       0.446    0.203   -0.022  0.581
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Check `str(stanford[, -(1:3)])` to see which column isn't numeric.

Comment: @Kryo One possible way this could happen is if the data is created by using `data.frame(cbind(...))`

Comment: What is the variable stanford?

Comment: Roland i checked data.frame': 137221 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ X536827A01_CMFS01_segMNT.txt: Factor w/ 2994 levels "-0.001","-0.002",..: 1612 2004 1574 53 1613 398 51 49 35 1887 ...
 $ X536827A02_CMFS01_segMNT.txt: Factor w/ 3315 levels "-0.001","-0.002",..: 1637 1948 25 1557 125 140 1816 1636 1520 1738 ...

Comment: Well, obviously columns you expected to be numeric are factors. Usually this happens during data import (e.g., you have NA values encoded as some text and didn't tell this the importing function).

Comment: @Roland, Ok i understood, so what can be done ?

Comment: @Kryo Fix your data import.

Comment: @Kryo Your `factor` columns can be converted to `numeric`.  Please check the update

Comment: @Kryo You could specify `colClasses=c('character', 'numeric'...)` in the `read.table` as well for the columns that need to be numeric

Comment: @Akrun if i want to specify numeric for columns 4 to 15?

Comment: @Kryo Try `stam <- read.table('file.txt', header=TRUE, sep='',
       colClasses=c(rep('character',3), rep('numeric',12)))`  Please change `sep` as needed

Comment: @Akrun what if my dataset is a large matrix?

Comment: @Kryo It depends on how big your dataset is.  Normally, `rowMeans` is faster when compared to `apply` based methods

Comment: @Kryo Another option would be transpose the dataset and do `colMeans`.  Column means might be a bit faster though I am not sure whether the tradeoffs is really significant by doing the `transpose`

Comment: @Akrun..thank you ..this command  stam <- read.table('file.txt', header=TRUE, sep='', colClasses=c(rep('character',3), rep('numeric',12))) worked fine.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the data you posted.  I would check `str(stam)` to see if the columns are `numeric`.

```
data.frame(ProbeID=stam[,1], Means=rowMeans(stam[,-c(1:3)]))
 #         ProbeID  Means
 #1  CHR10FS00300029 0.4384
 #2 CHR10FS003018825 0.3464
```

#### Update

If the `numeric` columns start from `4` to `15`, you can convert those columns from `factor` class to `numeric` first

```
 stam[,4:15] <- lapply(stam[,4:15], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

and then apply the `rowMeans`

Or you can specify `numeric` in `colClasses` argument in `read.table`

```
stam <- read.table('file.txt', header=TRUE, sep='',
       colClasses=c(rep('character',3), rep('numeric',12)))
```

#### data

```
stam <- structure(list(robeId = c("CHR10FS00300029", "CHR10FS003018825"
), Chr = c(10L, 10L), Position = c(3000293L, 3018825L), Sample1 = c(0.132, 
0.524), Sample2 = c(0.135, 0.446), Sample3 = c(0.312, 0.203), 
Sample4 = c(0.724, -0.022), Sample5 = c(0.889, 0.581)), .Names = c("robeId", 
"Chr", "Position", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", 
"Sample5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: i pasted only a 2 variables from my dataset. actually it  has 137221 observation and 15 variables

Comment: @Kryo It doesn't matter whether you have 5 observations or a million dataset.  What I was trying to convey is to check the `str(stam)` and see if the columns are `numeric` or `character/factor`.  In that case, the `rowMeans` would not work.

Comment: It showing factor         data.frame': 137221 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ X536827A01_CMFS01_segMNT.txt: Factor w/ 2994 levels "-0.001","-0.002",..: 1612 2004 1574 53 1613 398 51 49 35 1887 ..

Comment: @Kryo Are all the variables factors?  Assuming that your `expected` numeric columns start from column 4 to 15.